# How does lighting work in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

Being a sci-fi show, Star Trek likes to flaunt its technobabble. Phasers work thanks to the nadion pulse in the discharge crystal, a transporter stores your quantum properties with a heisenberg compensator, and isolinear chips have replaced monotronic microtapes. The same can be said for various display technologies: in *The Next Generation*, the viewscreen is holographic, while the consoles use a "triaxial optical crystal" as a display medium, which basically makes them 3D LEDs.

But one thing I have never heard about was light. You'd think with how omnipresent it is in basically  everything that at least once a passing remark could have called for a Cherenkov bulb or whatever, but I just haven't found anything. So, if you know what kind of lighting technology the Federation employs, I'd be happy to know. Thanks.

Comment: It works extremely well, thanks for asking. In some cases [*all too well*](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/06TRxQ-jcRIDadtBh0diz2ZM1sY=/99x0:1179x720/1400x1400/filters:focal(99x0:1179x720):format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49055005/star-trek-into-darkness-lens-flare-screencap_1280.0.0.jpg)

Comment: Something something lighting panels. I'm sure there's sonething in the TNG Technical Manual about this.

Comment: __(Incandescent) Light Bulbs__
In _ENT: Acquisition_ Jonathan Archer complained that you can't just yank out an antimatter injector as if it was merely a light bulb.

Comment: @SillybutTrue - That doesn't indicate that that's what they have though. There's a bunch of references to baths and we know that they have showers.

Comment: The Cardassians were having some problems with their lighting, they weren't sure how many lights were visible. As I recall, they had to ask Picard to help them count.

Comment: The are probably modulating the frequency of the photon emitters (I know I do).

Comment: @Valorum for those heretics among you who have only watched through Voyager, but none of the newer series, what's that image from?

Comment: @FreeMan - From one of the appalling new films